# Product information tabs are not displaying fully for newly adding product. General, price etc., are missing in magento in 1.9.3.2

Tags: magento-1.9.3.2, product-tab

Product information tabs are not displaying fully while adding New Product. From Inventory its displaying. General, price, Images etc., tabs are not displaying. Anyone give the solution about how to enable those things. Is there anyway to check in database or in codes? [image]

Comment: Can you check if there is any JS errors in console? Or any errors in var/log or var/reports.

Comment: No errors bro. Is there any solution?

Comment: There should be. Check apache error log or nginx error.log

Comment: errors in console as "up of null" and "target of null".